# Pass variables through <slot> to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, slots

Child component:

```
Vue.component('v-data', {

  template: `
    <div class="v-data">
      <slot :visible-data="visibleData"></slot>
    </div>
  `,    

  computed: {

    visibleData(){
      return [1,2,3];
    },

  },

});
```

In parent component I am using it like this:

```
<v-data>
   <li v-for="x in visibleData">{{x}}</li>
</v-data>
```

but `visibleData` is not passed in the template. I should be able to get 1,2,3.

Is there a way to pass variables between components like this?

Comment: In Vue data gets passed down not up. You _might_ be able to create a computed property on your parent that just returns the property from the child. This probably won't work but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

You are definitely looking for `Scoped Slots`. With this, one can easily pass data from the child component to the parent such that data could be referred to in the template being passed on to the child component. You can use it to pass data from your child component as

```
<div class="v-data">
    <slot :visible-data="visibleData"></slot>
</div>
```

Which can be referred in the parent as

```
<v-data>
  <template #default="{visibleData}">
    <li v-for="(value, index) in visibleData" :key="index">{{value}}</li>
  </template>
</v-data>
```

Few things to note here

1. The properties can be referred to using the name of the slot. Here
   we are referring to the default slot thus using the keyword
   `default`.
2. We can use `Object Destructuring` to directly access the property
   passed to the parent component

Sanbox present [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/scoped-slots-6rspu)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Scoped Slots` So that parent can see the child's data.

```js
<v-data>
   <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
      <li v-for="x in slotProps.visibleData">{{x}}</li>
   </template>

</v-data>
```

I might have made some mistake here, but I'd recommend reading it here: [Official Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)